# Sieve of Eratosthenes - Removing non-prime from vector

Tags: c++, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I am trying to make this program work:

```
int main()
{
    // prompt user for max number
    // ...

    // generate vector containing all numbers from 2 up to max
    // ...

    // give value 1 to not-prime numbers
    // ...

    // remove all not-prime numbers with value 1
    // ...

    // print out all numbers (all remaining are prime)
    // ...
}
```

Everything works great, except the step where I need to recognize prime numbers and change their value to 1. I tried everything and I'm really out of ideas. Here is the last idea I had for that block of code:

```
// give value 1 to not-prime numbers
for (int i = 2; i < int(sqrt(max)); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < numbers.size(); j++)
    {
        numbers[numbers[j] * i - 2] = 1;
    }
}
```

, and obviously it doesn't work. Help!

Comment: Not sure I am following you, in [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), you start by assuming all numbers are primes, and discard number that are discovered as non-primes. Also, for more efficient code - an if condition that terminates the inner loop is needed if numbers[i] is not prime.

Comment: o_O ? you say you set NON prime to 1, and then you say you want to set prime ones to 1 ... which is it ? :)

Comment: I want to eliminate all non-prime numbers, this is just some unsuccessful attempt to show you my idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume number is a vector containing numbers from 2 to max (number[0] = 2)

Your loop should be :

```
// give value 1 to not-prime numbers
for (int i = 2; i < int(sqrt(max)); i++) // ok i are true numbers starting at 2
{
    for (int j = (i * i) - 2; j < numbers.size(); j + = i) // j are indices for numbers starting at i * i (i*j for j< i already seen) stepping by i
    {
        numbers[j] = 1; // as j as indices do it directly
    }
}
```

what could alse be written :

```
// give value 1 to not-prime numbers
for (int i = 2; i < int(sqrt(max)); i++) // ok i are true numbers starting at 2
{
    for (int 0 = (i * i); j < max; j + = i) // j are true numbers starting at i * i (i*j for j< i already seen) stepping by i
    {
        numbers[j] = 1; // index for j is j-2
    }
}
```

Comment: This works and gives proper value 1 to all non-prime numbers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should show more code in order for us to work with your tools. For instance, what is the type of `numbers` ? If you really are using C++, it is probably `std::array` or `std::vector`. I will assume you want to use an `std::vector` for convenience. Also, you should not use C-style cast like so : `int(sqrt(max))`.

So, here is what I would have done :
First, create a vector of booleans that has every indices from `0` to `max`. The index represent the number in the sieve, and the boolean value points out if this number is prime or not. To begin with, you need to assume that all numbers are prime, so you initialize your vector with `true`.

```
std::vector<bool> sieve(max+1, true); // Sets every value to true
```

I am including 0 and 1 in the sieve for convenience, but you can work with some `index-2` everywhere in your code. Just to set things up, I need to put `false` here :

```
sieve[0] = sieve[1] = false;
```

Then, you want to proceed with the sieve algorithm.

```
int limit = static_cast<int>(sqrt(max));
for (int i = 2; i < limit; ++i)
{
    // If i is a prime, proceed with multiples
    if (sieve[i])
    {
        // Here, i*j is a multiple of i, hence not a prime (except when j = 1)
        for (int j = 2; i*j <= max; ++j)
        {
            sieve[i*j] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

You can alternatively use this as the inner loop :

```
for (int j = 2*i; j <= max; j += i)
{
    sieve[j] = false;
}
```

So now, your sieve is completed : every index with a corresponding `true` value is a prime, you only need to print them ! You can either copy them into another vector and then print out this last vector, of directly print the indices corresponding to a prime.